# Generate blurDataURL from nextjs itself without third party api

Tags: next.js

Nextjs allows us to use `placeholder="blur"` for the images that we statically import first.

For other images, we can specify a blurDataURL, however this needs generating the `blurDataURL` for each image on the fly.

I have failed to find a way to generate that blurDataURL in nextjs itself instead of going for third party api's that provide that.

So my queries are:

1. How can we generate `blurDataURL` for dynamic images from within nextjs? (by using some library?)
2. How can we make nextjs just use `placeholder="blur"` for non statically imported images but coming from the same project folders?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use a third party library like [`plaiceholder`](https://github.com/joe-bell/plaiceholder) to generate the `blurDataURL` for dynamic images. That's also the recommendation in the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#placeholder.

Comment: For your second question, why would you not statically import the images if they're local to your project? See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#local-images.

Comment: @juliomalves coz e.g. i have a gallery of images with images named 1.png 2.png ... so i just wanna loop through them